# How to move DLL dependencies to another folder

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dll, dependencies, mahapps.metro

My WPF application is using MahApps.Metro, it require the `MahApps.Metro.dll` and the `system.windows.interactivity.dll`. How do I shift them to a folder, for example folder `bin` and still make them work? If I just shift them, the application would not start at all. Please help!

Comment: Just don't, there is no point to it.  Having to add a .config file so you can use the `<probing>` element just adds a failure mode.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be best if you left all these DLL files alone and let the .NET Framework sort it all out. If you have to move them anyway, you may edit the properties of a reference and set the `Copy Local` property to false, so it won't output the DLL file when compiling.

In you App.cs file (assuming you're using C#) add the following:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
}

Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name.StartsWith("MahApps.Metro"))
    {
        System.IO.BinaryReader stream = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("bin/MahApps.Metro.dll", FileMode.Open));
        byte[] assembly = stream.ReadBytes((int)stream.BaseStream.Length);
        return Assembly.Load(assembly);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Edit the above code to suit your needs so that it will work exactly the way you want it to.

You will have to verify that all the DLL files you're using are the same version as the one being targeted, or .NET will throw an exception. Also, the DLL file may not exist and loading the stream might raise some problems if it is used on a network location. All in all it is likely to work, but it's probably not worth the trouble.